# Problems using Select in gorp

Tags: go

I'm receiving the following error when trying to SELECT with [gorp](https://github.com/coopernurse/gorp):

```
No table found for type: Post
```

Here's what my code looks like:

```
type Post struct {
    Id         int64  `db:"post_id"`
    CreatedAt  int64  `db:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt  int64  `db:"updated"`
    Title      string `db:"title"`
}

var list []*Post
_, err := dbMapper.Select(&list, "SELECT * FROM posts")

if (err != nil) {
    fmt.Fprintf(writer, "%s", err)
    return
}

for _, item := range list {
    fmt.Fprintf(writer, "%s\n", item.Title)
}
```

I'm adding the table like this:

```
dbMapper.AddTableWithName(Post{}, "posts").SetKeys(true, "Id")
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the line `err := dbMapper.CreateTablesIfNotExists()` ? That function appears a lot in the gorp tests so I figure it may be necessary.

Comment: Yes, i have used that. That just an excerpt of my complete code.

Comment: Whether you use `dbMapper.CreateTablesIfNotExists()` to create the table should have no bearing on Gorp's ability to use that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you're doing anything particularly wrong. I ran your example locally using the `postgres` driver (you didn't specify which driver you are using), and it worked just fine - my guess is that there's some information missing here. Things to make sure of:

- Check that `dbMapper.AddTableWithName(Post{}, "posts")` got called for the table before attempting to use it. The error you refer to is normally returned when `AddTableWithName` was not called.
- Check that the table actually exists in your database, and that you're connecting to the correct database with (something like) `sql.Open("postgres", "user=postgres dbname=test")`
- When instantiating Gorp, make sure you're using the right dialect: `dbMapper := &gorp.DbMap{Db: db, Dialect: gorp.PostgresDialect{}}` in the case of Postgres
- This could be related to an older version of Gorp - it's been a couple of months since this question was asked, upgrading now might resolve the issue.

Other than that I think we'll need more information to get to the bottom of this one.